# Trouble connecting MQTT client to MQTT server in Android in isolated network

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot-greengrass

I have a Greengrass core (Jetson TX2) broadcasting an isolated access point so different IoT devices can communicate with each other. the access point works as I was able to have one device to communicate to the core through OSC protocol.

Right now I am trying to get my smartwatch (running WearOS) to communicate with AWS Greengrass MQTT. This requires a SSL connection along with a group certificate provided by the core. My implementation works when the core and the smartwatch both connect to a network with active internet connection. However, when I try to communicate them through the isolated access point, the smartwatch is unable to communicate with the core

I am implementing the communication through `paho.mqtt.android` with a `socketFactory` to store my keys and certifications. I am not sure what cause my app to not be able to communicate with my core processor

I have tried to isolate the problem and it seems like the smartwatch did connect to the access point and retrieve and IP address. However, the `paho.mqtt.android` library does not use that IP address to initiate the MQTT connection

this is how I implement the client from the watch

**AWSMQTTService.kt**

```
 // ... other code
 socketFactory = AWSIotSslUtility.getSocketFactory(
            applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.groupca),
            applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.fc7334298c_certificate),
            applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.fc7334298c_private)
        )
        mqttClient = MqttAndroidClient(this, "ssl://${getEdgeEndpoint()}:8883", getDeviceName())
        val mqttOptions = MqttConnectOptions()
        mqttOptions.connectionTimeout = 5
        mqttOptions.isAutomaticReconnect = true
        mqttOptions.socketFactory = socketFactory
        mqttClient.connect(mqttOptions, null, object : IMqttActionListener {
            override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                debugLog("success")
            }

            override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable) {
                debugLog("failure")
                Log.e("Jarvis/err", "Failure", exception)
            }

        })
```

**AWSIotSslUtility.kt**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package com.shelltechworks.jarviswear.lib.utils

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter
import java.io.*
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
import java.security.cert.Certificate as Certificate
import java.security.*
import java.security.Security
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory


/**
 * This is a helper class to facilitate reading of the configurations and
 * certificate from the resource files.
 */
object AWSIotSslUtility {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun getSocketFactory(
        caCrtFile: InputStream,
        crtFile: InputStream, keyFile: InputStream
    ): SSLSocketFactory {
        Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
        val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")

        val caCert = cf.generateCertificate(caCrtFile)

        val cert = cf.generateCertificate(crtFile)

        // load client private key
        val pemParser = PEMParser(InputStreamReader(keyFile))

        val pemRawValue = pemParser.readObject()
        val converter = JcaPEMKeyConverter()
            .setProvider("BC")
        val key: KeyPair
        key = converter.getKeyPair(pemRawValue as PEMKeyPair)
        pemParser.close()

        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        val caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
        caKs.load(null, null)
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert)
        val tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509")
        tmf.init(caKs)

        // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate
        // us
        val ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
        ks.load(null, null)
        ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert)
        ks.setKeyEntry(
            "private-key", key.private, "".toCharArray(),
            arrayOf(cert)
        )
        val kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
            KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
        )
        kmf.init(ks, "".toCharArray())

        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
        context.init(kmf.keyManagers, tmf.trustManagers, null)
        return context.socketFactory
    }
}
```

I expect this to connect and print `success` to the debug log. However, I received this error

```
2019-05-29 16:18:31.259 13475-13475/com.shelltechworks.jarviswear D/Jarvis/AWSMQTTService: failure
2019-05-29 16:18:31.270 13475-13475/com.shelltechworks.jarviswear E/Jarvis/err: Failure
    MqttException (0) - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.12.1 (port 8883) from /192.168.167.239 (port 41415) after 5000ms
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:715)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.12.1 (port 8883) from /192.168.167.239 (port 41415) after 5000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the solution. Turns out by default Android `networkManager` will not bind itself to WiFi connection that doesn't have Internet access. Furthermore, if the device have cellular capability, it will bind to instead.

As far as I know, there are no solution to disable this functionality without rooting the device so I have to manually/explicitly bind the WiFi interface to a process in my app

```
private fun bindAppToWifiNetwork() {
        val builder: NetworkRequest.Builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        val connectivityManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(builder.build(), object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
            }
        })
    }
```